# C# WPF MVVM | Change Binded to StatusBar Vars

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, statusbar

So, I have a statusbar as UserControl.

Model:

```
public class StatusBarModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _status;
    public string Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set
        {
            _status = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Status");
        }
    }

    private int _p_value;
    public int P_Value
    {
        get { return _p_value; }
        set
        {
            _p_value = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("P_Value");
        }
    }

}
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class StatusBarVM : BindableBase
{
    readonly source.elements.StatusBar.StatusBarModel _model = new source.elements.StatusBar.StatusBarModel();
    public StatusBarVM()
    {
        _model.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => { RaisePropertyChanged(e.PropertyName); };

    }

    public string Status
    {
        get { return _model.Status; }
        set { _model.Status = value; }
    }

    public int P_Value
    {
        get { return _model.P_Value; }
        set { _model.P_Value = value; }
    }

}
```

And for example I wanna change *Status* variable from others ViewModels.
How I can do it? I have seen examples with only buttons and etc.

Comment: In MVVM you can nest ViewModels in each other. You often have VM's that Expose VM's wiuch Expose VM's. The highest one will becaome the de-fato Application View Model. | However a Command Pattern with Shortcuts and a Messaging Systems might also be the droids you are looking for.

Comment: VM's Hierarchy?)

Comment: Do you use Prism.Wpf?

Comment: Yeah, I use Prism.Wpf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve your requirement. as @bitclicker says, you can use static class that hold its value. But I think It is too much that makes it static class, because that variable value may be used only two `viewmodel`.

I suggest you communicate between two view model. you will find Prism's `event aggregator` or you could implement your own event publish-subscriber model. making your own event pub-sub model would help you to make a first step into the `design pattern`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static class to hold that value.

```
public static class Globals()
{
    public static StatusBarModel GlobalStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Then whenever you want to alter it you just do

```
Globals.GlobalStatus.Status = "something";
Globals.GlobalStatus.P_Value = 14;
```

does that accomplish what you need?

Comment: In that case I must make an Instanse of StatusBarModel, or It'll makes exceptions.   And it still not works. StatusBar didn't changed.

Comment: I juxt can not stress enough how bad a idea it is to use static here. It is a extremely common beginners trap. A static field that a instance is assigned to - that is about as close as I ever go to static.

Comment: that's fair enough, a static class is not suitable in this case. I'm still learning and appreciate your feedback